# Инвентори файл для ansible

Tags: ansible, terraform, tftp

Создал tf файл в терраформ
'

```
resource "local_file" "hosts_cfg" {
  content  = templatefile("${path.module}/hosts.tftpl", {
    webservers = yandex_compute_instance.web,
    database = yandex_compute_instance.database,
    storage = yandex_compute_instance.storage
  })
  filename = "${path.module}/hosts.cfg"
}'
```

Шаблон

```
    '[webservers]

%{~ for i in webservers ~}

${i["name"]}   ansible_host=${i["network_interface"][0]["nat_ip_address"]}
%{~ endfor ~}

[database]

%{~ for i in database ~}

${i["name"]}   ansible_host=${i["network_interface"][0]["nat_ip_address"]}
%{~ endfor ~}

[storage]

%{~ for i in storage ~}

${i["name"]}   ansible_host=${i["network_interface"][0]["nat_ip_address"]}
%{~ endfor ~}'
```

Выходит ошибка что не верно. Помогите понять как задать верный шаблон, или я не правильно передаю переменные? В итоге после запуска нужен инвентори файл с адресами для трех групп.

Comment: Абажди-абажди. Ты с помощью синтаксиса и бинарника терраформ хочешь создать ini файл для ansible? Я правильно понял?

Comment: какая ошибка-то ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45489534/best-way-currently-to-create-an-ansible-inventory-from-terraform - тут вроде корректно описано всё.